# Trying to get solid physics working coherently

Tags: physics

I'm trying to make an animation of photos falling onto a surface for an intro. To do this I created a large plane (the ground) which I set to passive mode, then created 28 smaller planes, arranged them via randomizing (and a little hand moving).

[Here is the file with my test so far](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVYiJ1IztP7wO1G4K8j1Ke39bW7OFVDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Finally I try to apply active rigid body physics to one of the planes and copy it to all of them. My problem is that I can't get any coherent output from this.

At first, the single first plane (plane.001 on the file linked) fell through the floor plane. I did a lot of tests including solidifying the floor plane, etc. Until finally I changed the shape of the falling plane to mesh, and it started working.

So I notice this test plane bounces around for a very long time, and I wanted a short bounce, so I tried setting bounciness but it did nothing. Eventually I settled on setting Damping translation and Rotation in Dynamics to a pretty high set of values (0.816 and 0.809). This seemed to achieve a shorter more "realistic" bounce around. So I copied the rigid body settings to all other planes ("copy rigid body settings") and... a couple planes (I think plane.005 and plane.012) fell through the "floor"...

Doing a lot of tests I eventually found that if I changed the Dampening Translation for those two planes a tad (one mouse pull) they stopped falling through.

Now the problem is that the end result was pretty "unrealistic", a few planes ended up resting in "air", a few planes ended up in various hard rotations (I expect them all to end flat on the floor plane), and one danced around with no end, bouncing back and forth.

More tests later I find that if I change the Shape to Convex Hull, all the planes but TWO (Plane.025 and Plane.026) fall through the floor. But those two planes, behave exactly as I want them to.. I tried changing the Dampening Translation a little for some other of the planes as a test, but they still fall through the floor... How can I stop all the planes from falling through? And have them all act "rationally" like Plane.025 and Plane.026?

How many things am I doing wrong? And which ones? :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes rigid bodies are really tricky, changing the size of the hole scene is sometimes the solution. You could also try the same scene with soft and collision bodies, if they are photos, it would be more accurate since they have to bend a little bit.